# Angular 4 form input is being reset

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ngmodel

I have a form that is being generated like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dag1; let i = index">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Product..." [value]="dag1[i].product.productName" [matAutocomplete]="product" [formControl]="productControl">
        <mat-autocomplete #product="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let product of options" (click)="editInput(product, i)">
                    {{ product.productName }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Hoeveelheid..." name="hoeveelheid" [(ngModel)]="dag1[i].hoeveelheid" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Tijd..." name="voeding_tijd" [(ngModel)]="dag1[i].voeding_tijd" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <span (click)="removeDag1(item)"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></span>
    </div>
<span (click)="addDag1()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>
```

When I add another row of inputs with:

```
 <span (click)="addDag1(1)"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>

 // Component
 addDag1(){
    this.dag1.push(this.newSegment());
 }
```

The new input fields are displayed but the former input field row is being emptied, but the values of that row are still set like so (considering I added hoeveelheid = 50 and voedingtijd= 12:30):

```
"voeding_tijd": "12:30",
"hoeveelheid": "50"
```

Why are my input fields being emptied while the values are still set?

EDIT:

newSegment() code (just creates an empty model instance):

```
 newSegment() : Voedingssegment{
     let voedingssegment = new Voedingssegment();
     voedingssegment.product = new Product();
     return voedingssegment;
 }
```

Model used with `dag1` :

```
    constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public productcode?: number,
    public product?: Product,
    public voeding_tijd?: string,
    public voeding_dag?: string,
    public voedingschema_id?: number,
    public hoeveelheid?: number)
```

Comment: Please share more code of your component (ex.: `newSegment()`). Also, I noticed that you are passing a parameter on `addDag1(1)` that is not processed on your component.

Comment: @BogdanC correct, I will update my question, thanks.

Comment: Try also changing names of input something like `name="hoeveelheid{{i}}"`

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change also `name` attribute value of each `input` element:

```
<input name="hoeveelheid{{i}}" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must track your array items. Otherwise the whole ngFor is rerendered. That's why you lose your inputs values.

Try that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dag1; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

And implement the function as follow:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: The values are still not being set when implementing this.

Comment: When you inspect the html generated by *ngFor, do you see that the whole list is rerendered ? In Chrome html elements blinks when they are rendered.

Comment: I don't think it does.. it only renders the new elements it seems.. :/

Comment: So you mean that when you add another field, the others are still emptied ? Without `trackBy`, do you see any difference when you inspect the page ?

Comment: No, theres no difference with or without `trackBy`

Comment: Can you add a example of your dag1 model please.

Comment: I tried something similar in local. It works fine :(. By the way you should not use formControlName and ngModel together.

Comment: gurkan's comment fixed my problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm ok, in fact you should not even define name="..." since your are using template driven form (or reactive form, no sure because both are used in your post). But maybe setting name attribute was causing bug. Maybe you could simply remove it.